# Webrtc handling multiple streams, reduce bandwidth

Tags: javascript, webrtc

**Hey Folks**

I am new on WebRTC and have a question about how to start and stop a WebRTC track to save bandwidth.

My backend provide multiple video streams so my SDK looks like this:

```
a=ssrc:3671328831 msid:user3339856498@host-602bca webrtctransceiver2 
a=ssrc:3671328831 cname:user3339856498@host-602bca
a=mid:video0 

a=ssrc:3671267278 msid:user3339856498@host-602bca webrtctransceiver3 
a=ssrc:3671267278 cname:user3339856498@host-602bca 
a=mid:video1
```

My goal is to let the user choose which stream they can look,
my problem is that, tracks they are added from RTCPeerConnection already send data.
when I set the `track.enabled=false` it also send data with full bandwith.

Is there a way to control start and stop they track so that no data is transmittet (RTCRtpReceiver)

thanks

Comment: You need to send a message to your media server to request him to stop sending media to you.